# Regex match varying number of words

Tags: javascript, regex

Software - Adobe Professional XI

Programming - JavaScript with **regular expression** to match wild card words

Background - I have multiple pdf drawings with a title block, using java script, digital signature fields are added based on the location of the word **(by matching with regex)**.

Currently am testing to see if words are present for revision 1 of a drawing title block.

The script searches for the Revision number 1 followed by a date, a title (with a varying number of words) and 4 sets of initials.

The number 1 is static, (the date, title and initials are all wild cards as they are different for each drawing).

I am using regular expressions to match the words.

This part of the regular expression finds the number 1 and date (this is working).

```
^1\s[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{2}
```

The rest of the regular expression is not matching the title and initials (this is not working)

```
s\w+(\s+\w+){1,8}
```

If anyone can help with the regular expression to match the words and initials that will be most appreciated.

Once the regex matching is working will split at each location of the 4 sets of initials so the javascript can add digital signature fields at these locations.

Can assistance also be given on how to split words with regex too?

Here is the entire script (the javascript is working, help needed for regex only)

```
numWords = this.getPageNumWords(0);
// number of words on page
// loop through the words on page
for (var j = 0; j < numWords-1; j++)
{ // get word pair to test 
    ckWords = this.getPageNthWord(0, j) + ' ' + this.getPageNthWord(0, j + 1); // test words 

    // example of word string
    // 1 26.05.16 THE REINFORCEMENT REVISED MM SB AE GM

    if (ckWords.match(/^1\s[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{2}\s\w+(\s+\w+){1,8}/))
    {
        console.println(ckWords);
    }
}
```

[pdf of title block with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRSNB.jpg)

Comment: Have you considered using split() instead of a reg ex?  Then, if needed, you could perform a regex, or any other test, on each word separately.

Comment: Can you match the back side of the string like this?
`(\s+\w\w){1,4}$`  You want just the initials, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the initials to to the end of the regular expression, so you can match them separately.

```js
ckWords = '1 26.05.16 THE REINFORCEMENT REVISED MM SB AE GM';

match = ckWords.match(/^1\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\s\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,8}\s([A-Z]{2})\s([A-Z]{2})\s([A-Z]{2})\s([A-Z]{2})$/);
console.log(match);
```

This will put the initials in capture groups 1 through 4 of the match.

Also, don't forget that `.` has special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape them to match them explicitly.

Comment: The regex did not work as a whole, I have tested the part with the initials at the end.  regex needs to find

Comment: /**error accessing property**/  I have also added an image to the end of the original post so you and see that the text is not altogether as a sentence in the title block, however after copying and pasting the text from the pdf to notepad it contains white spaces between the words (also a big thankyou for taking the time to help me)

Comment: I don't know what `this.getPageNthWord()` does, but it seems like it's not constructing the string the way you've shown in your question.

Comment: That seems to be a totally different problem from the regexp. If you can figure out how to make the string like what you've shown, the regexp will work.

Comment: You are correct, your regex should work, I need to reprogram this.getPageNthWord().  I will try to fix this with javascript and I will get back to you if I can get this to work.  Once again, thank you very much for your time in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```js
// some string with variable spaces and variable number of title words
var words = '1    26.05.16  THE   REINFORCEMENT  REVISED    MM  SB   AE  GM';

// match for:
// possible spaces at the start
// a 1
// variable spaces
// a xx.xx.xx date
// variable spaces
// any number of words that are not the initials, separated by variable spaces
// variable spaces
// four initials, separated by variable spaces
// possible spaces at the end
var matches = words.match(/^\s*1\s+\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\s+((?:\w+\s+)+\w+)\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+([A-Z]{2})\s*$/);
console.log(matches);

// replace variable spaces in title with single spaces
console.log(matches[1]);
matches[1] = matches[1].replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(matches[1]);
```